# Count the total pairs of two characters in a string

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, numbers

Basically I need to count the total number of agrupations inside a string, this is to display some information like an advise of the total number of opened submarked expressions in a RegularExpression application.

Then I need to count the total number of closed "()", not the total of "(" and the total of ")" separated.

For example in this string:

```
Hello (world)
```

The expected result would be: 1 closed

Here:

```
Hello (world) ((how are (you)?
```

The expected result would be: 2 closed and 2 opened

And here:

```
Hello ) ( World?
```

The expected result would be: 2 opened

Just pleae can something give me ideas of which can be the improved way to calculate them?

I got the total amount of "(" and ")" characters, now I don't know what to do.

> UPDATE:

I test with this string example:

```
(((X)))
```

But I get 4 unclosed and only 1 closed, I'm using this code:

```
Public Function Replace_All_Characters_Except(ByVal str As String, _
                                              ByVal chars As Char(), _
                                              replaceWith As Char) As String

    Dim temp_str As String = String.Empty

    For Each c As Char In str
        For Each cc As Char In chars
            If c = cc Then temp_str &= cc
        Next cc
    Next c

    Return temp_str

End Function

    Dim Total_Parentheses As String = Replace_All_Characters_Except(TextBox_RegEx.Text, {"(", ")"}, String.Empty)
    Dim Total_Unagrupated As Integer = Total_Parentheses.Replace("()", String.Empty).Length
    Dim Total_Agrupated As Integer = (Total_Parentheses.Length - Total_Unagrupated) \ 2

    MsgBox(Total_Parentheses)
    MsgBox(Total_Unagrupated)
    MsgBox(Total_Agrupated)
```

Comment: What is the expected result for "Hello ) ( World"?

Comment: @Kevin the expected result would be 2 opened, thanks for comment

Comment: What's wrong with just walking over the string in a loop and incrementing/decrementing two integers, as appropriate, depending on what the current character is?

Comment: @Alex Paven is a little bit more difficult than that, the Loop need to be intelligent to increment the ")" amount only if before that character is presented a "(" precedent, and the same for the "(" character, I have a headache. sorry for my english

Comment: Well yes; you'd check first if the 'open' number is larger than 0. I didn't say just increment the numbers willy-nilly but they are all pretty simple checks. Unless there are additional requirements: 2 opened for the last example isn't really clear, it's only one opened and one 'closed but unopened'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a Stack here

```
Stack<char> stack = new Stack<char>();
string input = @"Hello (world) ((how are (you)?";
//string input = "Hello ) ( World?";

int closed = 0;
int opened = 0;

foreach (var ch in input)
{
    if (ch == '(')
        stack.Push('#');
    else if (ch == ')')
    {
        if (stack.Count == 0)
            opened++;
        else
        {
            closed++;
            stack.Pop();
        }
    }
}

opened += stack.Count;

Console.WriteLine("Opened:{0} Closed:{1}", opened, closed);
```

**EDIT**

```
    Dim stack As New Stack(Of Char)
    Dim input As String = "Hello (world) ((how are (you)?"
    'Dim input As String = "Hello ) ( World?"

    Dim opened As Integer = 0
    Dim closed As Integer = 0

    For Each ch As Char In input
        If ch = "(" Then
            stack.Push("#")
        ElseIf ch = ")" Then
            If stack.Count = 0 Then
                opened = opened + 1
            Else
                closed = closed + 1
                stack.Pop()
            End If
        End If
    Next

    opened = opened + stack.Count

    Console.WriteLine("Opened:{0} Closed:{1}", opened, closed)
```

Comment: This answer is nice, because it is O(n) complexity. By comparison, mine is O(n^2) in the worst-case of N/2 nested matched parens, assuming `String.replace` is an O(n) operation.

Comment: I don't know how to translate that to VB.NET to test it, can you do it please?.

Comment: good one (+1). Actually I over-complicated things with a wrong example and after seeing your code, realise about that. In any case, I don't think that you should post C# codes in a VB.NET question; I am saying that independently upon what the OP has said now.

Comment: @ElektroHacker I added a VB version. Sorry for the delay but I had to learn VB :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to remove all of the characters from the string except parentheses. Then, iteratively remove closed pairs from the string until none remain. The remaining characters are unmatched. Pseudocode:

```
string sanitize(string s, List<string> valid_characters){
    string sanitized = "";
    for (char c in s){
        if (valid_characters.contains(c)){
            sanitized.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sanitized;
}

string s = ")Hello((World)())(";

s = sanitize(s, {"(", ")"});
int total_parens = s.length;
while(s.contains("()")){
    s = s.replace("()", "");
}
int unmatched_parens = s.length;
int matched_parens = total_parens - unmatched_parens;
int matched_pairs = matched_parens/2;
```

Here, ")Hello((World)())(" becomes sanitized to ")(()())(", and `total_parens` is 8. it reduces down to ")(())(", ")()(", and finally ")(". `unmatched_parens` is 2, and `matched_pairs` is 3.

Comment: Thanks for the comment before; my answer was completely off (should have read the question properly). But as far as I said it to I4V too...: I don't think that answering with C# to a VB question should be acceptable. If you want to answer a VB question and you have a C# code you should perform the conversion (or just post the algorithm or the ideas).

Comment: whats up when you reduce this example string?: "((()))", I translated by myself the code to vbnet but I don't get the expected result with that example, that would be 3 closed tags.

Comment: "((()))" should reduce to "(())" after one iteration, "()" after two, and "" after three iterations. Then `matched_parens` equals 6 - 0, so `matched_pairs` would equal 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the number of "opened situations" as described in the question, the best way I can think of is a loop (called via function):

```
Private Function isOpen(inputString As String) As Integer()

    Dim outArray(2) As Integer
    Dim outOpen As Integer = 0
    Dim outClose As Integer = 0


    Dim openCount As Integer = 0
    Dim closeCount As Integer = 0
    For Each curChar As Char In inputString
        If (curChar = ")") Then
            closeCount = closeCount + 1
            If (openCount > 0) Then
                outClose = outClose + 1
                openCount = openCount - 1
                closeCount = closeCount - 1
            ElseIf (openCount = 0) Then
                outOpen = outOpen + 1
                openCount = 0
                closeCount = 0
            End If
        ElseIf (curChar = "(") Then
            openCount = openCount + 1
        End If
    Next

    If (openCount <> closeCount) Then
        outOpen = outOpen + Math.Abs(openCount - closeCount)
    End If

    Return New Integer() {outOpen, outClose}
End Function
```

Which is called by doing:

```
Dim temp() As Integer = isOpen(inputString)
Dim totOpened As Integer = temp(0)
Dim totClosed As Integer = temp(1)
```

Comment: This appears to count the number of opening parens and closing parens. I think the OP wants "matched pairs" and "unmatched parens". Ex. "()()()()(" has four matched/closed pairs, and one open/unmatched.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the update, I misread this bit. Will update my answer right away.

Comment: Like @Kevin said that's what I need

Comment: thanks I will try it because with @Kevin answer i'm getting unexpected results

Comment: @ElektroHacker OK. I just tested the I4V one and seems to work fine (actually, helped me to realise about a problem).